# Local variable vs data. Huge loss in performance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, cesiumjs, scoping

I have a VueJS and Cesium project that is having a performance issue in regards to a degradation in frame-rate. I know where the issue is, yet, I don't know why or how to work around it.

```
export default {

    name: "Map",

    components: { ... },

    data: function () {
        return {
            viewer: {}        
        }
    },

    methods: { ... },

    mounted() {

        // 150-200 FPS; but no access to the viewer object outside of this component.
        let viewer = new Viewer('cesiumContainer');

        // 20-30 FPS; but yields me the access I need for other components to utilize.
        this.viewer = new Viewer('cesiumContainer');

        ... rest of my source code ...
    }
```

I can maintain well above 150-200 FPS with all the content I need to display versus an abysmal 20-30 FPS. I have eliminated the rest of my source code and simply have just tried rendering the Cesium world using just the above source code and this still happens - which is why I believe this is the root of my entire problem. But I do not understand why is this.viewer causing such a huge performance hit.... What can I do to resolve the problem?

**EDIT #1:**

Here is a sandbox incorporating Vue and Cesium: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-satoshi-1mog9

Using the search function at the top right, go to "Grand Canyon National Park, AZ" and use the 'Ctrl' and mouse to angle the camera to see the terrain. You should get something like this (note the low FPS and sluggish response rate):

[image: Low FPS]

However, if I do the same thing making viewer a localized variable, the response rate and FPS is far superior:

[image: High FPS]

Comment: Assigning to a prop in the data section automatically makes your object and all its props reactive and if these props change their values frequently this can impact on a performance.

Comment: could you somehow create a sandbox with this scenario?

Comment: @V.Sambor take a look at the sandbox I posted.

Comment: I'll take a look this evening and let you know if I see something

Comment: @Anatoly this is probably a stupid question but is there a way to prevent this from happening on specific objects? I mean, the whole point of Vue is to create reactive objects so I can modify them elsewhere within others components. So this will defeat the purpose of me having Vue in the first place. 

I'd imagine what is happening here is that the viewer object is being constantly watched and triggering updates to the viewer property; regardless of user input. Hence the huge slowdown when I use `this.viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer")` vs `let viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer")`.

Comment: If you don't need to make it reactive, could you assign it to a variable outside of the `export default`?

Comment: Maybe you could have a member function return a reference to the viewer from inside a closure?  So that other components could request a reference to the viewer without making the viewer a child of the component.

Comment: ```let viewer = new Cesium.Viewer(...);

this.getViewer = function() { return viewer; }
```

Comment: on my computer I see exactly the same FPS in both cases... :-|

Answer (score 0):

From anatoly's comment:
Assigning to a prop in the data section automatically makes your object and all its props reactive and if these props change their values frequently this can impact on a performance.

To avoid this, create your variable *outside* of the `export default {}` object.

It will look like this:

```
var myCesiumObj = null

export default {
    name: "",
    components: {...},
    mounted: function() {
        myCesiumObj = new Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    },
    data() {
        return {
            /* Do not put it here */
        }
    },
    methods: {...},
}
```

Note you will **not** need to use `this.` to access the variable, it will be available everywhere in this component.